# Layout добавить в начало

Tags: java, android

Обычно, чтобы добавить элемент, используется:

```
linearLayout.addView(viewEl)
```

Этим он добавиться в конец контейнера. Как добавить в начало? То есть, чтобы, при вертикальной ориентации, вью было выше остальных элементов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотри перегруженные методы:

```
void addView (View child,int index)

void addView (View child,int index,ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)
```

Comment: если не трудно пример можете показать?

Comment: linearLayout.addView(viewEl, 0)  Так думаю